# check if user is typing between two characters textarea

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string, recursion

I have a textarea which by default will have any type of string and a user cannot type unless he is typing inside an opening and closing bracket, such as "Leave[]" I can type inside the bracket but not outside it can be nested too till n levels such as Leave[ Nested[ Test[] ] ], i want a function to check if the user is typing inside the brackets to return `true` otherwise `false`

```
const checkIfTypingBetweenBrackets=(prev:string,current:string):boolean =>{

// Code goes here

}
```

Comment: Just to check my understanding, whenever the textarea receives input, you want to check whether it is correctly nested between square brackets. So, "Leave[Test[Again[Nested[]]]" is OK, but for example "Leave[Test[Again[Nested[]foor]]" or "Leave[Test[Again[Nested[]]bar]" is not. Correct?

Comment: No we have to check if the user is typing between brackets so there will be a default text like Leave[Test[Nested[]]] now i can only type between the brackets but not outside of the brackets, Leave[Test (I can type here also because its in the brackets) [Nested[This is what i type]]] see i type inside the brackets. But i cannot do this "Leave[Nested[]] I cannot type here or before"

Comment: And they can type & delete such brackets? So let's say the original input is `foo[]` then user edits it to `foo[bar bla]`, this seems to be allowed by your rules, and then edit it again to be `foo[bar] bla]`, i.e, they simply inserted `]` after `bla`. Are they allowed to edit the `bla]` part now? Beware, text editing is (very) hard, with a lot of edge cases to handle.

Comment: So anything between the opening and closing bracket is allowed? i.e.  "Leave[Nested[this is fine]]", "Leave[Nested[]so is this]", "Leave[this too Nested[]]". Did I get that right? It might help if you edited your question to expand on your requirements. Also @Kaiido raises a good point. What happens in that case?

Comment: Yes you are right, and we are allowed to edit between an opening and closing bracket, such as foo[bar] bla], foo[bar]]]] bla] it has an opening and closing bracket, doesn't matter what we type, i just need a function which returns boolean if the user is typing between an opening and closing bracket, but it should do it carefully like " foo[ " i cannot type then , the function will return false

Comment: So you could simplify this to test the value of the textarea to see if it matches: some optional text ("leave" in your first example), a square bracket, some more optional text, a final square bracket. If so, return true, if not return false. Does that sound like it would work?

Comment: By default it will be Leave[ ] or it can be nested also like Leave[ Nested[ Test[  ]  ] ] . i am using keyword type to tell you where i can write  "Leave[ type Nested[ type Test[ type ]  ] ]", if thats the case return true, if its like this then return false as am not writing in the brackets "not type Leave not type[ type Nested[ type Test[ type ]  ] ] not type"

Comment: Ok, I understand a bit better, but there are still too many unknowns. E.g. will the structure always be provided at the start (e.g. "Leave[ Nested[ Test[ ] ] ]") or is it possible to start with "Leave[ Nested[ ] ]" then change that to "Leave[ Nested[ Test[ ] ] ]" and have the same rules apply? To me it seems like you need to define what your requirements more clearly. I would encourage you to edit your question to specify your requirements, then maybe I can help.

Comment: The start of the structure will be Leave[ ] and then as i give space or type anything api will be called which dropdowns and those dropdowns will have structure Like this Test[ ], Nested[ ], Foo[ ]

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the requirements, the fact that there can be nested brackets doesn't really matter. All that matters is what's inside the outermost brackets.

So what we can do is check the current `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` positions before the `<textarea>` receives the input and compare it against the first index of a `[` and the last one of a `]`.
You'll also want to take special care of some inputs like backspace or forward delete so that they don't break the outermost brackets:

```js
const textarea = document.querySelector("textarea");
textarea.onbeforeinput = (evt) => {
  const { selectionStart, selectionEnd, value } = textarea;
  const bracketStart = value.indexOf("[");
  const bracketEnd   = value.lastIndexOf("]");

  if (selectionStart <= bracketStart || selectionEnd > bracketEnd) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
  if (evt.inputType === "deleteContentBackward" && selectionEnd === bracketStart + 1) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
  if (evt.inputType === "deleteContentForward" && selectionStart === bracketEnd) {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
  // If you want to handle these ones, you'd need to measure the closest word and check if it's attached to your brackets.
  if (evt.inputType === "deleteWordBackward" || evt.inputType === "deleteWordForward") {
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea>Leave[]</textarea>
```

*Note: I didn't perform extensive tests on this, and text editing is a real complex matter, so there may be some edge cases that this snippet doesn't handle*.

Comment: This is what I thought initially, but it seems there is more at play here than checking what's between the outermost brackets (see OP's comments).

Comment: @JamesHibbard well... I can't be 100% sure it's what they're after, (moreover since they're aren't really responsive, I was hoping that showing them *a* solution would help them define their issue), but from what I read, they are still at the step "prevent writing outside of the brackets". Which this answer addresses. The next step would then be, parse all the brackets before calling the API. But that would be for another question, the two problems are only tangentially related.

Comment: Absolutely. And FWIW, yours is a nice answer. I learned a trick or two from it.

Comment: @Kaiido based on your answer and comments , i fugured it out,  i am using ReactJS so it would be a different there , i am adding the answer so if anyone need, Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As @Kaiido mentioned i dont have to worry nested brackets and just need to focus on the outer most brackets, so based on his solution

Write the following function wherever you want

```
const checkIfTypingBetweenBrackets = (previousText, currentText) => {
  let prevBracketOpen = previousText.indexOf("[");
  let prevBracketClose = previousText.lastIndexOf("]");
  let currentBracketOpen = currentText.indexOf("[");
  let currentBracketClose = currentText.lastIndexOf("]");

  if (
    currentBracketClose - currentBracketOpen >
    prevBracketClose - prevBracketOpen
  ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Now use it on onChange before saving the value in state

```
  <textarea
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => {
        // Here value argument is the previous value as we have not stored the latest value in state, and e.target.value is the latest value
        let ifBetweenBrackets = checkIfTypingBetweenBrackets(
          value,
          e.target.value
        );
        // Only update the value in state if user is typing between brackets
        if (ifBetweenBrackets) {
          setValue(e.target.value);
        }
      }}
    />
```

Answer (score -2):

*The input state is initialized with square brackets. The checkTyping function checks if the cursor is inside the square brackets or not, if it is outside the bracket, the input is ignored.*

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

const BracketText = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState('[]');
  const textareaRef = useRef(null);

  const checkTyping = (text) => {
    const { selectionStart, selectionEnd } = textareaRef.current;
    return selectionStart > 0 && selectionEnd <= text.length - 1;
  };

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const currentValue = e.target.value;

    if (checkTyping(currentValue)) {
      setInput(currentValue);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        ref={textareaRef}
        value={input}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BracketText;
```

Comment: I have updated the code, may be it will helpful for you.